# The value provided for the key MinimumOSVersion '7.0' is not acceptable

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I uploaded an ipa file to iTunes connect via Application Loader today, there is no error during the upload. But as soon as I finish uploading, I receive an email from iTunes connect:

> This bundle is invalid - The value provided for the key MinimumOSVersion '7.0' is not acceptable.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Does this mean that iTunes Connect do not accept Apps that support iOS 7? 
I submitted successfully two weeks ago, and only changed some code for this version as an hotfix.

When I change the Deployment target from [7.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMNs6.png) to 
[8.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp3Dg.png), iTunes connect says 'completed processing'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be iTunes Connect's problem, I changed build number and submitted again, and there is no error this time.